# Set value for column based on two other columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, efficiency

I have a dataframe that has contracts with different order dates and I need to create a new column that assign a number to each contract if it has more than one order date. For example my sample dataframe looks something like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'contract': ['123A','123A','123A','123A','123B','123B','123C'],'prod': ['X1','M1','V1','D1','A1','B1','C1'],'date':['2019-04-17','2019-07-02','2019-04-17','2019-07-02','2019-04-17','2019-09-01','2019-08-02'],'revenue': [5688,113932,5688,49157,5002,892,9000]})
```

I need my final table to have another column with a unique contract id for each date. My final table from above should look something like this:

| contract | date | header_contract |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123A | 2019-04-17 | 123A_0 |
| 123A | 2019-07-02 | 123A_1 |
| 123A | 2019-04-17 | 123A_0 |
| 123A | 2019-08-02 | 123A_2 |

I have the following code that does what I need on a smaller dataset:

```
contracts_num = df['contract'].unique()
for cm in contracts_num:
    for idx,val in enumerate(df[df['contract'] == cm]['contract'].dt.date.unique()):
        df.loc[((df['contract'] == cm) & (df['contract'] == str(val))),'contract'] = df['contract'] + '_' + str(idx)
```

I'm trying to do it on a much larger dataset (around 50,000 contracts) and it's taking a really long time. Is there anyway to make it more efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) together with [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) as follows:

```py
df['header_contract'] = df['contract'] + '_' + df.sort_values(['contract', 'date']).\
  groupby('contract')["date"].\
  apply(lambda x: (x.shift() != x).cumsum()).astype(str)
```

In the `apply`, `x.shift() != x` is used to create a new series of booleans corresponding to if the date has changed in the next row or not. `cumsum` will then create a cumulative sum (treating all True as 1) which creates the suffixes for each group. This is then merged with the contract names to create the new column.

Result:

```
  contract prod       date  revenue header_contract
0     123A   X1 2019-04-17     5688          123A_1
1     123A   M1 2019-07-02   113932          123A_2
2     123A   V1 2019-04-17     5688          123A_1
3     123A   D1 2019-07-02    49157          123A_2
4     123B   A1 2019-04-17     5002          123B_1
5     123B   B1 2019-09-01      892          123B_2
6     123C   C1 2019-08-02     9000          123C_1
```